# What is the difference between these two declarations in react javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the class syntax to declare a react component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {value: ''}
    }

    doA(event) {this.setState({value: event.target.value})}

    doB = (event) => {this.setState({value: event.target.value})}

    render {
        return (
            <input type="text" onChange={this.doB}/>

            {*the following is wrong:*}
            {*<input type="text" onChange={this.doA}/>*}
        )
    }
}
```

If I try to handle `onChange` using `doA`, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

`doA`'s declaration looks more like a class method from Java, and `doB`'s declaration looks more like an anonymous function assigned to a class property. I would have thought using `onChange = this.doA` would keep `this` assigned to the class, but it's the other way around. `onChange = doB` keeps `this` assigned to the class.

I tried searching for explanations but I don't know the proper terminology, thus my search terms are poor.

On a side note: If I use `onChange = doA`, I get that error, but the input field will still update correctly. So `this.state.value` is changing, yet it's giving me that error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions in JavaScript lexically bind `this` for you. That's the reason `doB` works properly while `doA` doesn't.

If you bind `doA` in the `constructor`, things will work as expected using class syntax:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doA = this.doA.bind(this);
}
```